# How to wait for all asynchronously tasks?

Tags: ios, afnetworking, grand-central-dispatch

I download asynchronously some object, I store it in array. Next for each object I download some coordinates with geocoding (it is also asynchronously), and update my database for each object with new parameters which is coordinate. My method looks like this:

```
- (void)downloadObjectsWithTitle:(NSString *)title andHandler:(void(^)(NSMutableDictionary *result))handler {
    AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"GET"
                                                        path:nil
                                                  parameters:nil];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    [httpClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFHTTPRequestOperation class]];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        //I get here array of objects
        //now for each object I want to download geocoding localization so i called another asynchronyous method getLocationWithTitle:andHandler;
       for(int i = 0; i < resutArray.count; i++) {
           [self downloadLocationWithString:[dictionary objectForKey:@"string"] andHandler:^(NSMutableDictionary *result) {
               //update database;
           }];
        }
        handler(dictionary);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
    [operation start];
}
```

My question is how to downalod coordinates for each object and that fire:

```
handler(dictionary);
```

so wait for each coordinates download (for each object) before quit method (fire handler).

Thnaks for all sugestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maintain a count of all the tasks. When it's zero you're done.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using `dispatch_async` in `downloadLocationWithString:` on a concurrent queue:

```
dispatch_barrier_async(queue, ^{
    // will only be called after all the blocks submitted to queue have finished.
}];
```

(If you're using serial queue, simply call handler at the last line of the last block)

Answer (score 0):

Try a global flag. set NO first. In download block, after download complete set flag to yes. You can check that flag.

Comment: This solusion would be ok if i will have only one asking for geocoding. But for multi it wont works.

Comment: take global variable and assign it by total no. of downloads whenever download completes just decrease variable by 1. You can  check value of that variable if its 0 then all ur downloads are completed.